# How to draw a graph with shaded area by using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams, graphs

[image]

Anyone knows how to draw the graph in the picture by using Tikz?

Comment: this site doesn't provide service "we-do-your-task-for-you". this your third question without showing any of your effort to write a code for your image. now you should know, that such question is to broad and likely be closed.

Comment: The most difficult will be the pink (salmon?) border. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Without salmon. (Would be more straightforward with pgfplots, though.)

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm,tikz,x11names,dvipsnames,svgnames]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\tikzset{declare function={f(\x)=sqrt(1/\x);}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [latex-latex] (0,6) -- (0,0) -- (6,0);
\draw[blue,thick] plot[samples=50,variable=\x,domain=0.04:5,smooth] 
({\x+0.2},{f(\x)});
\path[pattern=north east lines] (0,0) -- (0,5) -- (0.24,5) --
plot[samples=50,variable=\x,domain=0.2:5,smooth] 
({\x+0.2},{f(\x)}) -- (5.2,0) -- cycle;
\node (SF) at (2.5,2.5) {$S_F$};
\draw[-latex] (SF) to[out=-160,in=70] ++(-2,-2);
\node[anchor=west] at (5.3,0.4) {$F(x)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

current_user: I was working parallel; in my example the pattern lines doesn't cross the function.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={font=\footnotesize}]
\fill[pattern color=black!70,scale=.5,domain=.2:5.5,smooth,pattern=north west lines] (0,0) -- (0,5) -- (.2,5) -- plot ({\x},{1/\x}) -- (5.5,0) -- cycle;
    \draw[scale=.5,domain=.18:5.5,smooth,red] plot ({\x},{1/\x});
    \draw[>=latex,->] (-.5,0) -- (3,0) node[above] {$F(x)$};
    \draw[>=latex,->] (0,-.5) -- (0,3);
        \node (a) at (1.5,1) {$S_F$};
        \draw[thick,->] (a) to[bend right] (.3,.3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

P.S.: I left at the top of the pattern a little space betwenn it and the function (as in the picture, too).

Output:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If it's a bad proposal, fell absolutely free to delete it!

Comment: @current_user Thanks! (I guess you cannot post it since the question is closed, otherwise I'd be happy to leave that question to you. I am just not a big fan of closing questions that are understandable, that's why I posted a quick answer. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, this was the problem! I just wanted to post it as an answer, but the question was, as you mentioned, closed. And yes, you were a little bit quicker than I was. ;) I really don't want to ruin your nice answer!

Comment: @current_user No worries! It is a nice answer!